# Sorting a List Based on a Given Order

Tags: functions, function-construction, sorting

Suppose I have the following input:

```
input={{1, 2, 3}, {-2, 4, 6}, {-1, 3, 6}}
```

How can I sort it according to this list:

```
order = {{a, b, c}, {a - b, a + b, a + b + c}, {a - c, a + c, a + b + c}}
```

The expected output is:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 3, 6}, {-2, 4, 6}}
```

EDIT:

If you compare the `input` list and the `order` list you would see that
`{a, b, c}` is `{1, 2, 3}`, `{a - b, a + b, a + b + c}` is `{-1, 3, 6}`, `{a - c, a + c, a + b + c}` is `{-2, 4, 6}`.
So I want to sort the input in this order:

```
{{a, b, c}, {a - b, a + b, a + b + c}, {a - c, a + c, a + b + c}}
```

or expected output is `{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 3, 6}, {-2, 4, 6}}`.

If you shuffle the input in any order for example `{ {-2, 4, 6}, {-1, 3, 6},{1, 2, 3}}` the expected output should be the same as `{a, b, c}` is still `{1, 2, 3}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `order` is not a very large list:

```
order = {{a, b, c}, {a - b, a + b, a + b + c}, {a - c, a + c, a + b + c}};
input = {{1, 2, 3}, {-2, 4, 6}, {-1, 3, 6}};

order /. Cases[Solve[input == #] & /@ Permutations[order], {{p__}} :> p]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 3, 6}, {-2, 4, 6}} *)
```

Comment: Yeah, this works.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand what you mean by "sort according to the given order". You haven't given an ordering, you've given an expected result, and it could be achieved through a variety of orderings. We'd need several examples to understand what you mean. But the simplest thing I see that will achieve your expected result is to sort by the reverse:

```
SortBy[input, Reverse]
```

`{{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 3, 6}, {-2, 4, 6}}`

Comment: All elements in the `input` belong to the order list `order = {{a, b, c}, {a - b, a + b, a + b + c}, {a - c, a + c, a + b + c}}`. For example, in the given example, if you assign `{a, b, c}` to be `{1, 2, 3}` then you would obtain the two remaning elements in the `input` but `{a - b, a + b, a + b + c}, {a - c, a + c, a + b + c}` by substituing values of `a=1, b=2, c=3`. So the problem is sorting the `input` list with the `order list`. In the example `{a, b, c}={1, 2, 3}` to be the first element but it's not always the first.

Comment: If I change the input to `input={{-2, 4, 6}, {-1, 3, 6},{1, 2, 3}}`, the expected output should also be the same. The method you gave seem to give the expected output but that is not what I want as it doesn't consider the given order list at all.

Comment: Of course the expected output of a sort will be the same if you just shuffle the input.  If my answer isn't correct, you need to provide an example input that it won't sort correctly. And, of course, tell us what the correct output should be.

Comment: Okay, let me add some more information.

Comment: Can you maybe just explain your ordering function in words? Given a list whose elements are lists of three integers, how should we sort such a list?

Comment: I just added it in my original post.

Comment: I see that. It doesn't explain anything. It just re-iterates what you already said, which I still don't understand.

Comment: Here are some test cases. I suggest that you provide expected sorted outputs for each: 1. `test1 = {{5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, {6, 7, 8}}`, 2. `test2 = {{5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 7}}`, 3. `test3 = {{5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, {6, 7, 5}}`, 4. `test4 = {{5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, {6, 7, 5}}`.

Comment: I apologize if there is a language barrier that is making it difficult for me to explain this clearly. I believe Domen may have understood what I meant. The test cases you have provided do not follow the format that I had specified through the `order` list. Therefore, I think I am unable to provide the desired output.

Comment: Oh. You're not talking about a general sorting function. Your inputs are already constrained. That was very confusing.